# How can I(or Paypal) validate post data that is sent to Paypal from a button on my site?

Tags: paypal

I'm using paypal website standard and passing my order id that is generated on my site via item_number field. I was wondering, how does paypal know that the content in the form has not been altered by user? For example, someone could just change the amount of $10 to $5 and paypal would not not have any way of knowing. I've doe this before with other payment processor, and they make me send them md5 hash of amount and some other data + secret key, but I am not sure if paypal has this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this article](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_encryptedwebpayments), I believe it depends on whether or not you are using "Payment Data Transfer". If you're just using a button, then you'll need to manually verify the payment amount before shipping. If you're using PDT, you should be able to verify the payment_gross amount sent back in the response from PayPal.

Comment: I'll be using PDT and IPN and will validate amount. Thanks for info and link.

Answer (score 0):

Your right -- in  general you can't keep someone from altering your data. If you must use PayPal (yeah, I know, no monthly fee) so far as I know you have three options:

1. Let PayPal host your button data. But this gives you little control over the process.
2. Manually verify each transaction, checking price etc before shipping item.
3. Using their API to receive completed transaction to automatically check data.

Another thing to watch out for is calculation of sales tax. PayPal's approach was too simplistic for our needs, which forced me to take control of the checkout process.

See this [link](https://cms.paypal.com/au/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_encryptedwebpayments).

Comment: Looks like it all comes down to using IPN/PDT and validating amounts. thanks for tips and link

Answer (score 0):

you should try to implement it using ipn, pdt is prone to not passing the variables from paypal to your website if the user does not press the "go to store" button. as what others had answered hosting your button would make it secure at the cost of flexibility. Here is a link on the variables that could be altered on hosted buttons https://www.x.com/people/PP_MTS_Haack/blog/2009/11/11/override-variables-for-hosted-and-encrypted-buttons , as you would look into the variables, you cant really change the important ones.